# Unable to access SFDC User Objects "EmailPreferencesAutoBcc" entity from SOQL/SOAP interface

Tags: salesforce, soql

The entity **"EmailPreferencesAutoBcc"** is accessible via Tableau connection to SFDC and the entity is a standard entity for User object.

When Accessed via SOQL on SOAP interface the following Error is throw.

```
No such column 'EmailPreferencesAutoBcc' on entity 'User'.
```

This is the corresponding SOQL i'm using:

```
select EmailPreferencesAutoBcc from User limit 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that User, which you use for SOAP call, has permission to Read this field.
Check [Set Field Permissions in Permission Sets and Profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=users_profiles_fls.htm) to find out where to check permissions.